# Compiled python script doesn't work on other machines

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I know that the title may not be very clear so here's my problem below:

I've made a mini application in python for contact management (it's a simple program.py + a notepad where the information are stocked+some photos). I've made an executable (.exe) to share it.
I've made it with pyinstaller. The .exe works pretty well on my laptop but don't work elsewhere. The error messages are the following:

```
No error messages generated.FormatMessageW;Parametre incorrect.
```

Then when I click Ok there is a second one:

```
Error loading Python DLL 'c\users....\_MEI50282\python37.dll
```

Comment: what exe file did you use? The one from the build folder doesn't work everytime. You need to use the exe file inside the dist folder.

Comment: yep I've used the exe file inside the dist folder

Comment: you need to use the entire dist folder.